# python codeacademy sending a letter

Tags: python

I'm trying to teach myself Python starting with codeacademy's course, and so far it's been going okay. However, I hit a snag in Student Becomes the Teacher 7/9. I wasn't able to find a thread discussing this issue, but if I missed one please feel free to let me know.

According to codeacademy I completed this exercise successfully, but I know there's something wrong with this code. When I play around with the code below in repl.it, get_average(student) returns the correct values. I've tested this by changing the grades around a bit just to be sure - but get_letter_grade(score) returns "A" for every student. I tried being more specific with the number ranges that were allowed (see below), but I keep having the same issue.

```
lloyd = {
        "name": "Lloyd",
        "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
        "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
        "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
    }
alice = {
        "name": "Alice",
        "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
        "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
        "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
    }
tyler = {
        "name": "Tyler",
        "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
        "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
        "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
    }

def average(numbers):
        total = sum(numbers)
        total = float(total)/len(numbers)
        return total

def get_average(student):
        homework = average(student["homework"])
        quizzes = average(student["quizzes"])
        tests = average(student["tests"])
        studentaverage = (homework * .1 + quizzes * .3 + tests *.6)
        return studentaverage

def get_letter_grade(score):
    if score >= 90:
        return "A"
    elif score >= 80:
        return "B"
    elif score >= 70:
        return "C"
    elif score >= 60:
        return "D"
    else:
        return "F"
```

I also tried changing the get_letter_grade(score) function a little to make it more specific/restricted (I may be thinking the wrong way; I'm very new at this) as below:

```
def get_letter_grade(score):
        if score >= 90:
            return "A"
        elif score >= 80 and score < 90:
            return "B"
        elif score >= 70 and score < 80:
            return "C"
        elif score >= 60 and score < 70:
            return "D"
        else:
          return "F"
```

But as stated above, I have the same problem: it returns "A" for every student, no matter how I alter their grades.

Any advice, insight, wisdom, etc. you care to share would be hugely appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: where are you using the `get_letter_score` function?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above code and it works perfectly fine without any changes.
Maybe if you can share the way in which you are calling the functions, I can shed some light on the erroneous procedure you may have been following. Below attached is the snippet of the code and its corresponding output.

```
lloyd = {
        "name": "Lloyd",
        "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
        "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
        "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
    }
alice = {
        "name": "Alice",
        "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
        "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
        "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
    }
tyler = {
        "name": "Tyler",
        "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
        "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
        "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
    }

def average(numbers):
        total = sum(numbers)
        total = float(total)/len(numbers)
        return total

def get_average(student):
        homework = average(student["homework"])
        quizzes = average(student["quizzes"])
        tests = average(student["tests"])
        studentaverage = (homework * .1 + quizzes * .3 + tests *.6)
        return studentaverage

def get_letter_grade(score):
    if score >= 90:
        return "A"
    elif score >= 80:
        return "B"
    elif score >= 70:
        return "C"
    elif score >= 60:
        return "D"
    else:
        return "F"

# To calculate the grades of each student
grade_tyler = get_letter_grade(get_average(tyler))
grade_lloyd = get_letter_grade(get_average(lloyd))
grade_alice = get_letter_grade(get_average(alice))

print(grade_lloyd)
print(grade_alice)
print(grade_tyler)
```

Output :

B

A

C

Further I also tried individually calling the methods and the results were as expected.

```
grade_A = get_letter_grade(95)
grade_B = get_letter_grade(85)
grade_C = get_letter_grade(75)
grade_D = get_letter_grade(65)

print(grade_A)
print(grade_B)
print(grade_C)
print(grade_D)
```

Output :

A

B

C

D